# Dependency injection frameworks promotes the use of the singleton pattern in spring

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to get my head around the fact that the spring IoC container holds just only one instance of an object that clients want to be injected with.

Let's define what is a singleton first

> An object with mutable states that can only be reached outside of the
>   stack, meaning it is residing in the method memory area (permanent
>   generation space) of the JVM

If you annotation a method in spring with `@Bean` shown below:

```
@Bean
public Student getStudent() {
    return new Student();
}
```

The container will execute this and stores it in the container so that it can inject in constructors like this:

```
@Autowire
class StudentService() {

    public StudentService(Student s) {
        this.s = s;
    }
}
```

All fine and dandy. But, isn't this just an another form of a singleton pattern? I mean, sure you have to inject it in order to use it, but what if we have mutable states in the student that clients need and causes an unexpected to show up in another client? Is it common to not have mutable states in a bean and just have methods?

Thank you

Comment: Yeah, but you can easily mock a `Student` and create another `StudentService` instance with it for testing purposes. And `StudentService` does not care where the `Student` comes from, who creates it, etc. If you have mutability in your beans then you have done fucked up :D.

Comment: You can always change to another type: prototype, request, session, etc.  Most beans that are singletons are interface based with other dependencies injected into their implementations (e.g. repository with pooled connection).  Rod Johnson knew what he was doing.  Objects like Student, that suggest method scope and instances, should be instantiated using new and not under the control of the Spring factory.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you should use `singleton` scope only for stateless beans.
From Spring [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html):

> [...] you should use the prototype scope for all beans that are stateful,
> while the singleton scope should be used for stateless beans.

When you obey this rule, situation you had described will never happen (i.e. shared mutable state).

So answering your question:

*Is it common to not have mutable states in a bean and just have methods?*

Yes, you should not hold the state inside beans with singleton scope.

Comment: Understood, thanks!

Comment: That's great! If it meets your expectations please consider accepting my answer.